# Display a block when all conditions are met in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block that I want to display if it matches the following conditions:

- not the weekend
- not a bank holiday (loop through an array of bank holiday dates
- outside a defined start and end time

I think it's close to working. I can get the swap working when testing against each condition but I think when trying to test all together my code/conditions seem a bit messy.

Here it is and I'd appreciate any help to get this working - to display when all conditions are true and not to display when false:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function () {

//set current date
var currentDate = new Date();

//bank holidays
var bank1 = { year: 2018, month: 9, day: 3 } ;
var bank2 = { year: 2018, month: 10, day: 14 } ;
var bank3 = { year: 2018, month: 11, day: 12 } ;
var bank4 = { year: 2018, month: 12, day: 10 } ;

//declare time variables
var startTime = { hour: 9, minute: 30 } ;
var endTime = { hour: 16, minute: 30 } ;

//set bank holidays in array
var bankholidays = [new Date(bank1.year, bank1.month - 1, bank1.day), new Date(bank2.year, bank2.month - 1, bank2.day), new Date(bank3.year, bank3.month - 1, bank3.day), new Date(bank4.year, bank4.month - 1, bank4.day)];

//set start and finish time
var starterTime = new Date(startTime.hour, startTime.minute);
var finisherTime = new Date(endTime.hour, endTime.minute);

//get current time
var myCurrentTime = new Date(currentDate.getHours(), currentDate.getMinutes());

//include logic for time in variable
var time = starterTime.getTime() <= myCurrentTime.getTime() && myCurrentTime.getTime() < finisherTime.getTime();

//get current date
var myCurrentDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate());

//set variable to store criteria when it's not a weekend
var notWeekend = currentDate.getDay() != 6 && currentDate.getDay() != 0;

//set logic to show block if it's not a bank holiday, if it's between 9.30 and 4.30 and it's weekday. Otherwise the block will show
if(time && notWeekend)

{

    $(".block").show();

}

else

{

//loop through array of bank holidays and compare each against and check if any are a bank holiday and display block if it is a bank holiday
    for (i = 0; i < bankholidays.length; i++) 

    {

        if(bankholidays[i].getTime() == myCurrentDate.getTime())

        { 

            $(".block").show();

        }

        else

        {

            $(".block").hide();

        }

    }

}

})();
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class = "block">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i cleaned it up for you. Main part is adding `$(document).ready` to it else it will not run at all.

had to clean it up to make sure the logic whas doing what its suposed to be doing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

//set current date
var currentDate = new Date();

//bank holidays
var bank1 = { year: 2018, month: 9, day: 3 } ;
var bank2 = { year: 2018, month: 10, day: 14 } ;
var bank3 = { year: 2018, month: 11, day: 12 } ;
var bank4 = { year: 2018, month: 12, day: 10 } ;

//declare time variables
var startTime = { hour: 9, minute: 30 } ;
var endTime = { hour: 16, minute: 30 } ;

//set bank holidays in array
var bankholidays = [new Date(bank1.year, bank1.month - 1, bank1.day), new Date(bank2.year, bank2.month - 1, bank2.day), new Date(bank3.year, bank3.month - 1, bank3.day), new Date(bank4.year, bank4.month - 1, bank4.day)];

//set start and finish time
var starterTime = new Date(startTime.hour, startTime.minute);
var finisherTime = new Date(endTime.hour, endTime.minute);

//get current time
var myCurrentTime = new Date(currentDate.getHours(), currentDate.getMinutes());

//include logic for time in variable
var time = starterTime.getTime() <= myCurrentTime.getTime() && myCurrentTime.getTime() < finisherTime.getTime();

//get current date
var myCurrentDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate());

//set variable to store criteria when it's not a weekend
var notWeekend = currentDate.getDay() != 6 && currentDate.getDay() != 0;

//set logic to show block if it's not a bank holiday, if it's between 9.30 and 4.30 and it's weekday. Otherwise the block will show
if(!time || !notWeekend)
{
    $(".block").hide();
}

//loop through array of bank holidays and compare each against and check if any are a bank holiday and display block if it is a bank holiday
for (i = 0; i < bankholidays.length; i++) 
{
    if(bankholidays[i].getTime() == myCurrentDate.getTime())

    { 
         $(".block").show();
    }
}


})();
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class = "block">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Since the text is visible by default you only have to hide it. this will eliminate the else clauses. So what you do is instead of checking if they make the check witch makes them visible. you check if they dont make the check and hide them.

Answer (score 0):

The is a bit of a mess because it is not divided into functions.
Create a function called "validateDateAndTime(date)" or something like that.
It will do something like:

```
return notWeekend(date) && notHoliday(date) && inWorkingHours(date)
```

Then create a function that toggles your block (it's usually common to cache the queries element to avoid multiple DOM queries). It gets true/false and shows/hides accordingly.
And then all you need to do it:

```
toggleBlock(validateDateAndTime(date));
```

It's hard to tell what architecture would suit you most but it would certainly makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var bankHoliday = function (date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < bankholidays.length; i++) {
        if (bankholidays[i].getTime() === date.getTime()) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false;
};

if (time && notWeekend && !bankHoliday(myCurrentDate)) {
    $(".block").show();
}
else {
    $(".block").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are several issues with your code and it being a mess is making it harder for you to figure out what is actually happening. I went ahead and cleaned up your code and did my best to put comments on each line attempting to explain what it's doing.

A key thing to note is that I moved all of the code into a namespace, attached to the ready event and call my function inside that event. This is not necessary for the code to function but it isolates it from potentially getting polluted and makes it easy for you to reference later in the code.

```js
// create a namespace for your application
var myApp = new (function(){

 // store a reference to this instance to reference later, use a constant for this
 const self = this;
  
  // store the bank holiays as actual dates in an array,
  // just do the math here for the 0 based index of months
  let bankHolidays = [
   new Date(2018, 8, 3),
    new Date(2018, 9, 14),
    new Date(2018, 10, 12),
    new Date(2018, 11, 10)
  ];
  
  // just store the bank hours as dates but disregard the date and 
  // just use the time later
  let bankHours = {
   open: new Date(1999, 0, 1, 9, 30),
    close: new Date(1999, 0, 1, 16, 30)
  }
  
  // This is a simple function to check if the times of a given date is
  // between the times of two other dates
  self.isTimeBetween = function(testDate, startDate, endDate){
   // construct a new date and time using testDate for the day info 
    // and the start and end dates for the times
   let startTime = new Date(testDate.getFullYear(), 
                 testDate.getMonth(), 
                             testDate.getDate(),
                             startDate.getHours(),
                             startDate.getMinutes());
                             
    let endTime = new Date(testDate.getFullYear(), 
                 testDate.getMonth(), 
                             testDate.getDate(),
                             endDate.getHours(),
                             endDate.getMinutes()); 
                             
    // getTime returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00
    // we can use this to see if testDate is between start and end
   return testDate.getTime() >= startTime.getTime() && 
       testDate.getTime() <= endTime.getTime();
  }
  
  // expose the function to call and set your UI
  self.toggleData = function(){
    // get the current date and time, just create a new Date will get that for you
    let today = new Date();
    // check if its a weekend
    let isWeekend = today.getDay() == 6 && today.getDay() == 0;
    // check if we are inbetween the open hours
    let isOpen = self.isTimeBetween(today, bankHours.open, bankHours.close);
   // check if its a holiday, use Array.some to test all the
    // holidays we stored earlier. 
    let isHoliday = bankHolidays.some(function(item){
     return item.getDate() == today.getDate() &&
          item.getMonth() == today.getMonth() && 
             item.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear()
    });
    
    // check if we need to show the block
    if (!isWeekend && !isHoliday && isOpen)
     $(".block").show();
    else
      $(".block").hide();
  }
})();

// attach to the ready function and execute your function
$(document).ready(function() { 
 // call my function inside the namespace I created
  myApp.toggleData();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="block">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```

Comment: If you want to run through test cases change `let today = new Date();` inside `self.toggleData` to construct the date and time you want to test.